# What's the difference between clEnqueueMapBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer

Tags: buffer, opencl

They can both transfer data from host to device right? 
So, what's the difference? One needs to create a buffer one doesn't? Thanks!

The explanation on khronos's website:

clEnqueueMapBuffer:

Enqueues a command to map a region of the buffer object given by buffer into the host address space and returns a pointer to this mapped region.

clEnqueueWriteBuffer

Enqueue commands to write to a buffer object from host memory.

Answer (score 6):

Writing the buffer means that you have 2 memory objects - one on host, which is allocated by malloc, etc and one on Device, which is allocated via OpenCL API.

Mapping means that you have one object, allocated by OpenCL API, and you are translating it's address into Host address space.

If your Device has memory from RAM, you would better use mapping - address translation takes less time than copying.

If your Device has separate memory, you will see no speed difference - data will be implicitly copied.

Anyway, mapping allows you to get rid of memory duplication.

Comment: What about if the initial buffer was allocated using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR? Doesn't that mean there (might be/is) only one memory object?

Comment: OpenCL standard says that in case of CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag usage, implementation may allocate auxiliary buffers on Device side for caching. This is transparent to user: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html

Comment: Agreed. And I guess according to Intel, you want to do your best to page align the memory: https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/ioclsdk/2013/OG/Mapping_Memory_Objects_(USE_HOST_PTR).htm.

Answer (score 4):

**clEnqueueWriteBuffer:** Enqueues a write of data from a memory pointer in the Host, to a memory buffer in the Device. It may take a small amount of time to complete, but after it finishes there will be no hidden thing. After the copy, the buffers will be completely detached and independent.

**clEnqueueMapBuffer:** Maps a host pointer to a Device buffer or vice-versa (CL_MAP_READ/CL_MAP_WRITE). This does not copy anything to the device, but states that you are mapping its contents to another buffer.
For example, if you map a buffer for writing it will give you a mapped pointer for writing. Each time you write to this mapped buffer, the OpenCL API "may" flush this to the device buffer. So, it "may" increase the speed of the read/write to these buffers. The drawback is that after writing to a map buffer you will need to unmap it, in order to ensure the data is flushed completely to the destination.

> Unless you desperately need more I/O BW for your application,
>   I would not recommend to start using Map Buffers yet. Plain writes and reads
>   are more simple, and error free actions for novel users.